# Preventing accidental builds in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I want to create a manually triggered Team City build that deploys our website to its live environment. I am hesitant to do this as I worry about people accidentally triggering the build.

I know I could semi resolve this by preventing access for most people or by making the deploy process slightly harder, two steps for example.

Are there any nicer techniques? Is it possible to have a 'Are you sure?' style dialogue?

Comment: Never, never, never have automatic deployment to a production environment *en masse*. Have it deployed to a staging environment, and then manually push it live. My $0.02.

Comment: @Gordon respectfully, I think that's perhaps an overly broad statement without knowing more about how Dan has things arranged.

Comment: It may well be, but I've had to deal with the mess that can happen as a result.

Comment: Hi Dan -- just checking in.  Were you able to get a good process in place?

Answer (score 27):

First off, you should take John Hoerr's advice and prevent people from running it unless they are a very small number of people.

But we can do even better, and prevent errant misclicks from people that should be able to run the build. Add a [configuration parameter that's a checkbox](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Typed+Parameters). This way, when someone hits the "run" button, it will quickly fail. They'll have to hit the ellipses on the run button, then click a checkbox next to a message like *are you sure?*.

To do that, add the parameter with a name like `confirm`, then hit the *edit* link. On the popup, click the *edit* button next to **Spec**. Change the *type* to `Checkbox`. Set *checked value* to `true`, and *unchecked value* to `false`. Or some other values that make sense to you.

Click `Save` to save the Spec, then go back to the *Edit Parameter* popup. Set *value* to `false`. This is the default value of the checkbox.

As the first thing you do in the script, check whether the parameter `%confirm%` is set to the string `"true"` or whether it's set to `"false"`. If it's `"false"` you want to `exit 1` immediately: the person running the build did not check off the `confirm` checkbox.

If you want, you can make the *Run Custom Build* popup come up every time. To do that, in the `Edit parameter specification` window, change *Display* to `Prompt`. The default value will still be to not do the deploy, but the dialog will pop up every time.

You can also make the label that shows up next to the textbox not be the parameter's name, but an arbitrary string. In the `Edit parameter specification` popup, make the `label` something like *Pinky swear that you want to do this?*

Comment: Good advice.  We also just setup a "confirm" parameter having just been through the embarrassing exercise of explaining the impromptu deployment to production when someone (me) clicked the wrong button.  Also, I've removed the production deployment build configuration from  the dashboard as an extra precaution.

Comment: Great advice, but can you elaborate on *As the first thing you do in the script*?

Comment: I have implemented the suggestions with a confirm checkbox and have a Nant script which fails the build based on this checkbox. This works great but is there a way to ensure that the checkbox always defaults to 'false' as currently it defaults to the previous checked state.

Comment: @RichardEv For the build configuration that runs, you don't want to do anything before checking if the user confirmed that they really want to run the build. It's a bad idea to `exit 1` in the middle of the deploy.

Comment: @JohnAskew I'm not sure -- I no longer do anything using TeamCity, nor have an instance of it I can use to test. Post a new question, and hopefully someone will get back to you. Alternately, contact [TeamCity support](https://www.jetbrains.com/support/teamcity/index.html) or file a bug.

Comment: I've done something extremely similar to this except I've required the person deploying to type in the target domain for production deployments.

Comment: **Important** Like John Askew mentions, once you have checked the checkbox, it will remain checked for future builds, making this solution almost useless.

Comment: I was also trying to prevent accidental builds (misclicks seem to be a problem) and I happened to do the exact same thing as this answer suggests as this. It's a shame that TC doesn't have some kind of functionality that allows this built-in. Also, as mentioned above, once it's checked, it remains that way. :(

Comment: Just tested this solution with Teamcity 2022.04 (build 108502), if you follow the instructions and define the default value in the "Edit Parameter" window to be false, this will prevent the checkbox from being checked the next time you click on run. So you always have to check the checkbox.

Comment: @DanielZ., it's still remaining on (well, set to specific value) for me while I am on the page even when the value is set and used after new login.

Answer (score 4):

The way that we do it is a two step process. Both steps have access limited to our deployment team. Let's use the production web server code as an example:

1. A build is manually run from Teamcity, building and deploying the production code to one non-public facing production server - the `Deploy` server. Due to our extensive caching and CDN use in production, this is a bit different than our `Staging` environment.
2. A second "build" is manually run from Teamcity, which is essentially just a trigger for a command line/powershell script to deploy the code from the `Deploy` server to the production servers.

Since both builds have their access limited, it prevents accidental deployment to production almost entirely. For example, if one of the few engineers who have access to the production builds came in and accidentally ran the second deploy script without running the first build, it would just re-deploy the code from the deploy server, which is the code that is already on production. This would not cause any damage.

While I certainly trust all of the engineers involved in our deployment process, I like the reassurance of a two-step process for production. Better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're on the right track by using TeamCity's role-based access to prevent most folks from running the production deployment.  For teammates that do have the privilege, I encourage them to hide/remove the *Deploy to Prod* configuration from their dashboard.  You can do this by clicking the **X** to the right of the configuration.  This has been for us an effective way to prevent casual mis-clicks.  When you do want to run the *Deploy to Prod* build, you can browse directly to it via the project page.

Answer (score -1):

For production environments, we require confirmation of the domain being deployed to. Here's a simple way of accomplishing this:

1. Edit the Deployment build step.
2. Click to add a new configuration parameter.
3. Set the following parameter specifications:

   - Label: Confirm Target
   - Description:  Confirm the production environment being deployed to.
   - Display: Prompt
   - Type: Text
   - Allowed Value: Regex
   - Pattern: **[TYPE IN YOUR DOMAIN (remember to preced periods with slashes)]**
   - Validation Message: Deploying to the wrong domain, dweeb!

Comment: Teamcity saves the value for the next deployment... Is there a way to clear out that value each time?  I'm trying to make users type in production every time they do a production deployment.. But the second deployment prepopulates the value.

Comment: @AlexSpence Unfortunately I don't have a solution for that nagging problem.

Comment: @AlexSpence @Mario To get around the memoization of build parameters, I force user to enter something that changes with each deploy ... the build counter of the dependent build.  Here's my bash build step:

`if [ %confirm% != %dep.Builds_Ci.build.counter% ]; then
  echo Failed to confirm the right build counter number, should have been %dep.Builds_Ci.build.counter%
  exit 1;
fi`